# Capital Ezh (U+01B7)

Tags: unicode, characters

What is the easiest way to obtain the capital version of **tipa**'s letter `\textyogh` (which is apparently LATIN CAPITAL LETTER EZH U+01B7, Ʒ)?

Comment: This is not a duplicate: see [Wrong closure as duplicate](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3921/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a similar letter in Cyrillic fonts, CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ABKHASIAN DZE U+04E0.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[X2,T1]{fontenc} % or OT1 in place of T1

\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\CYRABHDZE}{X2}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyrabhdze}{X2}
\newcommand{\Ezh}{\CYRABHDZE}
\newcommand{\ezh}{\cyrabhdze}

\begin{document}

\Ezh\ is the letter, with \ezh\ for the lowercase version.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

the unicode manual identifies yogh as U+021C (capital) and U+021D (lowercase).

there are cross references to ezh: U+01B7 (uppercase) and U+0292 (lowercase).
these more closely match the images in both the tipa manual and the "phonetic symbol guide" (pullum & ladusaw).

if looking for a font, the phonetic fonts from sil.org are good candidates.
[doulos sil](http://software.sil.org/doulos/) should be usable with xetex or luatex.